# IIS7: limit traffic for the server

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

How to limit traffic for the whole server with IIS7?

There is a limit feature for a site, but it works only for a separate site:

[image]

Also there is Bitrate Throtting plugin for IIS, but as I know it can be configured only for a separate user:

[image]

Is there a way to configure traffic limits for the whole server, not for a single web-site?

**UPDATE:**
The solution is (thanks to @Arpit) setting `<webLimits maxGlobalBandwidth="1000000" />` to machine config. But be careful! There is an error in IIS docs: you should type `maxGlobalBand[w]idth` (with lower case `w`), not `maxGlobalBand[W]idth` (with upper case `W`).

Comment: I don't think it's possible, IIS allows you to limit traffic for a site, but making it generic is not a good idea since the server might be hosting multiple sites and this feature might come handy to divide equal bandwidth for websites.

Comment: The thing is that it's my hoster's requirement: I have to limit traffic generated by my server. It would be ok if I have a single site on it, but I have more than one.

Comment: @Lenin I think that you must go with a program that stay on the network driver and make that limits. Check this page: http://diggfreeware.com/five-best-bandwidth-limitershaper-software/  I use the cfosspeed.

Comment: @Aristos I wouldn't like to add additional tier between web-site and user's browser. Also I'm sure there's an overhead, although it might be not very big

Comment: @Lenin This programs act like firewalls, everything pass from them, and there is the place for this limitation, on the port 80.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, I have not tried it yet but you can give it a go -

In IIS7, Select the server and open the **Configuration Editor**. On the right hand pane, there is an option to search the configuration. We are looking for `webLimits` here.

This might be the key. More information about `webLimits` can be found [here](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/weblimits)

**EDIT** - 
I found this attribute for `webLimits` which should help :

*`maxGlobalBandwidth` - Specifies the maximum total bandwidth for the server. Setting the value to 0 enables unlimited bandwidth for the server.
The default value is 4294967295.*

Comment: I have `<webLimits />` tag in my applicationHost.config, but when I changing it to `<webLimits maxGlobalBandWidth="1000000" />` I start getting an error: **Configuration file is not well-formed XML** pointing to my app pool's config: `\\?\C:\inetpub\temp\apppools\MySite\MySite.config`. I tried to look at it but the xml seems fine, I didn't change. Can you make any suggestions?

Comment: @arpit- Can you check the quotation marks around maxGlobalBandwidth your xml file? I once got this error because quotes were different and I typed them in instead of copying them once.

Comment: I found the error. There is a misprint in IIS docs: `maxGlobalBandWidth` must be written with lower case `w`

Comment: @Arpit, thank you for your help. I don't think I would find the solution without it.